# chrome Network emulateNetworkConditions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This my first JS Chrome extension.

I want make YouTube only offline.

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "limit",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "limit",
  "permissions": ["storage","tabs","webNavigation","debugger"],
  "background": {
     "scripts": ["background.js"],
     "persistent": false
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js:

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(function(e) {
    alert(e.url);
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
        alert(tab.id);
        chrome.debugger.attach({tabId:tab.id}, version, onAttach.bind(null, tab.id));
        chrome.Network.emulateNetworkConditions({offline: true, latency: 100, downloadThroughput: 1, uploadThroughput: 1});
      });
}, {url: [{hostContains: 'youtube.com'}]});
```

background.js line 5 and 6 not working , I do not know if this is the right way to write it or not !

Comment: What is your Problem? describe .

Comment: background.js line 5 and 6 : I do not know if this is the right way to write it or not !

Comment: Can you add any details like error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.